# Is there a difference between perfect, full and complete tree?

Tags: graphs, terminology, trees

Is there a difference between perfect, full and complete tree? Or are these the same words to describe the same situation?

Comment: See also: [Difference between "Complete binary tree", "strict binary tree","full binary Tree"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359660/difference-between-complete-binary-tree-strict-binary-tree-full-binary-tre) on StackOverflow

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference between the three terms and the  difference can be explained as:

**Full Binary Tree:** A Binary Tree is full if every node has 0 or 2 children. Following are examples of a full binary tree.

```
         18
       /    \   
     15      20    
    /  \       
   40   50   
  /  \
 30  50
```

**Complete Binary Tree:** A Binary Tree is complete Binary Tree if all levels are completely filled except possibly the last level and the last level has all keys as left as possible.

```
            18
       /         \  
     15           30  
    /  \         /  \
  40    50     100   40
 /  \   /
8   7  9
```

**Perfect Binary Tree:** A Binary tree is Perfect Binary Tree in which all internal nodes have two children and all leaves are at same level.

```
           18
       /       \  
     15         30  
    /  \        /  \
  40    50    100   40
```

Comment: For me the term "complete binary tree" means what you call "perfect binary tree".

Comment: no, they aren't the same. As you can see in the above example, all the leaves in the  complete binary tree are not at the same level whereas in case of perfect binary tree they must be at the same level.

Comment: What I'm implying is that your terminology is not really standard. Other people mean something else when they use the exact same expressions.

Comment: okay got that. I'll provide u with a better answer shortly. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 4):

These words don't have a standard definition. A full binary tree could be one in which every node has either none or two children. A complete binary tree of height $h$ could be one in which all nodes up to level $h$ have two children. I have never heard of the adjective *perfect* used to describe trees.

That said, a complete binary tree of height $h$ usually means what I wrote above.

Comment: There's also one of these for trees that are complete up to height $h-1$, and level $h$ is filled "from the right". (Tree representations of heaps look this way.)

Comment: Tree representations of heaps are complete, if additionally the last level is filled then it is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

A complete binary tree is on in which every level excepts possible the last level is completely filled and every node are as far left as possible but for a full binary tree every level has the maximum number of nodes in it

Answer (score 0):

A full binary tree has all it's nodes with either none or two children. A complete binary tree of height h could be one in which all nodes up to level h have two children. A perfect binary tree is a tree which is both full and complete.

Comment: Says who? The accepted answer says that these terms have multiple inconsistent definitions so how can you say that one definition is the only correct one?